# SQL Select Max ID Where Condition Is Met

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with 50-100k rows.  I have an auto-increment ID field, and another field called Main_Port.

I want to select the last ID where Main_Port = x.  And I want it to be efficient.

What I'm using right now is:

```
SELECT max(MANIFEST_ID)FROM MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest where Main_Port = x
```

Is this the best way to do it?

The table has potential to grow to 500k+ rows

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about your data structure and indexing structure it's tough to say "this will be efficient.  The query you use :

```
SELECT max(MANIFEST_ID)
FROM   MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest 
WHERE  Main_Port = x
```

Could be quite efficient, depending ....

- Is there an index on   Manifest.MainPort ?  or (Manifest.MainPort, ManifestID desc) ?
- What sort of density are we talking on Main_Port?  Meaning, for a given main_port how many distinct manifest ID's are there?

To add some perspective, 500k rows isn't that big in database terms.  You've seen a few variations on queries here, and one may be marginally faster than another, but real speed is going to come down to having a good index ( Main_Port, ManifestID desc).  Alternatley, if you really want to dig deep you'll want to materialize a summary view. Here is a [decent explanation](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) of the mechanics of materialized views.

Comment: MAX doesnt give you the last, it gives you the bigger value.

Comment: @Diego -  Agreed, but the question is a bit unclear as to what `last` means.  He mentions that the table has an auto-increment field, but fails to specify if that field is Manifest_ID.  If ManifestID is that field, the max is the latest (within a given `main_port`).  If something else is going on, without more information we have no way of knowing the last ID.

Comment: @EBarr Thanks, great explanation. Manifest_ID is auto increment. The only indexing I have going on is Manifest_ID.  There are 5 Main_ports.  There is no limit on Manifest ID's per main port. Ideally, they would be split up evenly. Theoretically, they all could be on one main port.  Anyways, I think I'll just leave the query like it is

Comment: Well, I'm a sql server guy, but file up your equivalent of performance monitor & look at execution plans.   Run your query without any additional indexing,  add the index on (Main_PortI & ManifestID desc) and look again.  I expect you'll see stark differences.    Given, that Main_Port is not very selective (5 total) ...the density you would get in a materialized view (5 rows total) would likely result in a single read and 0ms for your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MANIFEST_ID FROM MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest where Main_Port = x ORDER BY MANIFEST_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Seems to be the other way, but I don't know if it would be more efficient than yours

Comment: top 1 is a sql syntax, not mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Order By if you want, although using MAX is fine.

```
SELECT MANIFEST_ID FROM MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest where Main_Port = x ORDER BY MANIFEST_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

MAX doesnt give you the last, it gives you the bigger value. And it is bad because it has to scan all rows to get the bigger value.

I would do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest
where Main_Port = x limit 1
order by ID desc
```

Comment: + order by MANIFEST_ID DESC ?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Manifest_ID column is auto increment column then you can achive this below query also:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 MANIFEST_ID FROM MANIFEST_MSS.dbo.Manifest WHERE Main_Port = X order by    MANIFEST_ID DESC
```

Comment: top 1 is a sql syntax, not mysql